# Advances in recent time in Von-neumann self replication idea

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models

I have read about Von-neumann self replication from  [Theory of Self-reproducing automata](http://cba.mit.edu/events/03.11.ASE/docs/VonNeumann.pdf), which are lecture notes reconstructed from lectures in book of the same name. [Theory of Self-reproducing automata](http://e-x-a.org/stuff/books/cs/von%20Neumann%20-%20Theory%20of%20Self-Reproducing%20Automata.pdf)

> Its looks really interesting that neumann has formalize this even far before the discovery of DNA. I'm looking the work now from biological perspective and the work by [Jeremy England](http://www.englandlab.com/) his paper on [Statistical Physics of Self-Replication](http://www.englandlab.com/uploads/7/8/0/3/7803054/2013jcpsrep.pdf) and other similar work in irreversible biological process.

The work that Von-neumann did was around 50's. Is there any recent relevant work in this field based on the neumann's work. One that i could see is [Enhancing the Robustness of
Self-Replication Processes](http://www.alife.org/alife8/proceedings/sub2058.pdf)

Thank You.

Comment: I think you are asking about Cellular Automata?

Comment: Yes connection between cellular and artificial automata and advances along the same line, For example von-neumann had not made the C (Complexity) completely formalized. People in bio-physics world have already made advances doing that and far even more using a connection between statistical irreversiblity and entropy production.

Comment: @ABD i meant was in kinematic model of self replication. Coz i have seen that model use in recent paper in PNAS in scheduling problem solving of yeast self-replication rather than his 2nd model (cellular automaton).

Comment: Von's automata are a bit complicated with 28 states , and have been already advanced into much simpler automatas like Elementary Cellular Automsta and Conway's Life ... you can find related topics in this journal (www.complex-systems.com/archives.html) ... if you really want some real advances, then wait for the 4th volume to come out ... i wrote a paper grouping Elementary CA and Conway's Life into a single model of computation and should be published there (approx. 1-2 weeks more, it supposed to be published already but its journal's delay).

Comment: If you go to Google Scholar, search on the lecture notes you mention, and then search "Cited by", you'll find many papers that cite it, from which you should be able to find any follow-on work that's based on it.

Comment: In Science Fiction: Andreas Eschbach, "Lord of all things".

Comment: Related: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33272/has-a-replicator-ever-been-built/48150#48150

Answer (score -1):

For those who don't know, I am the world's only producer of a von Neumann 29-state self-replicating cellular automaton.
Indeed, respecting vNCA, I am the world's expert.  Ask Sayama (U Binghamton), Reggia(U of Maryland), or Adamatzky (U of South of England).
While DW may be a moderator, he does not know anything about von Neumann's cellular automata, I dare say he has not designed such self-replicators, and he certainly had not designed a machine zygote.  For my design of a machine zygote, see here:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235432119_Computational_Ontogeny
One more thing, it is 29 states, not 28.

Comment: This looks like link only answer, probably addressing comment not the question.

Comment: Those who are addressing this question are ill suited, versus my knowledge of the topic.  I am challenging all of StackExchange.  You present to me someone who knows more about vNCA, and then I will bow out.

Comment: Good for you, but this is irrelevant if you cannot present it in SE compilant way as the answer. Moreover, this is knowledge-sharing (Q&A) cooperative site not made for self-promotion and roasting others.

Comment: What I notice is that you don't actually want to share knowledge.  I am telling you the facts.

Comment: Clearly, my best approach is to refuse to share any further knowledge with any other participant of SE.

Comment: This post is almost entirely about yourself and says nothing that really answers the question. That's not what this site is about, regardless of how much you know.

Comment: As stated above, all that you have provided here is a link to a potential answer. We want answers to stand on their own and not be dependent on external links. Would you like to [improve your answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/104133/edit) by adding some basic information on how your machine zygote is relevant to Von Neumann self replication? Thanks. Additionally, answers are not the place to to mention who you are or what you did. You are free to put any information about yourself in your [profile page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/edit/98542)